# Render special template if Json set is empty

Tags: templates, jsrender

Usually I have a dataset with many records like:

```
data = [
   { name1: value, name2: value },
   { name1: value, name2: value }
];
```

Want to use one template when there are more than 0 records in my array but want to apply a different template when data is empty like:

```
data = [];
```

The {{if}} conditionals work fine when one of the named elements are empty but how do I check if the root array is empty and select a different template based on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that various ways, but here is one approach.

Pass your data array to the JsRender template, with the boolean `noIteration` flag set to true (see [example](https://www.jsviews.com/#tmplrender@sample-noiteration)):

```
html = myTmpl.render(data, true);
```

so that the template renders just once, for the array.

Then use a template similar to the following, with a `{{for}}` tag to iterate and an `{{else}}` for the case where the array is empty...

```
<script id="myTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{for}}
        this will render once for each item in the array
    {{else}}
        this will render if the array is empty
    {{/for}}
</script>
```

(See [Using the {{else}} tag with {{for}}](https://www.jsviews.com/#fortag@else))

Similarly, you can pass in your array as part of the data:

```
var viewModel = {myArray: data, ...},
  html = myTmpl.render(viewModel);
```

then write:

```
<script id="myTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{for myArray}}
        this will render once for each item in the array
    {{else}}
        this will render if the array is empty
    {{/for}}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw that {{for}} iteration in the docs but missed that you had to pair it with"noIteration". Makes sense now.